# Java Guava Resources.getResource doesn't work from far jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, guava, spark-submit

I've created a far jar using maven assemble which includes properties files. It works from my IDE. However, after I `package` everything my application doesn't work.

I have all my properties files in `src/main/resources` and I can confirm from using `jar tf farjar.jar` that I see properties file in the root folder

However, when I run my program from that fat jar I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource ci.properties not found.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource(Resources.java:191)
    at io.conde.config.ConfigReader.read(ConfigReader.java:23)
    at io.conde.SparrowHalToS3.main(SparrowHalToS3.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Here's my pom.

```
 <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And here's my code using Guava.

```
public Properties read(String environment) throws IOException {
        final URL url = Resources.getResource(format("%s.properties", environment));
        final ByteSource byteSource = Resources.asByteSource(url);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = byteSource.openBufferedStream();
            properties.load(inputStream);

            return properties;
        } catch (final IOException ioException) {
            LOG.error(ioException.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (final IOException ioException) {
                    LOG.error(ioException.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Removed you supplemental configuration for resources cause it's default. Furthermore to get resources you need to set `getResource("/...")`.

Comment: now I'm getting `resource /ci.properties not found.`

Comment: Does your jar file correctly contain the resources? Have you checked the content of the jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `SomeClassThatShouldBeInTheSameJar.class.getResource(<whatever>)` instead? `Resources.getResource` is basically just a wrapper that uses either the current thread's context classloader or the classloader for `Resources.class` itself to look up the resource. While in many cases it will work, in some cases you'll need to do something different.